# How to apply a specified Pose Library pose to the rig via python script?

Tags: python, rigging, pose-mode

I'm trying to create a Python script which **applies a pose from an imported pose library** to the rig in my scene. I can set the pose library and the active_index of it:

```
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].objects['Armature'].pose_library = bpy.data.actions['PoseLib']
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].objects['Armature'].pose_library.pose_markers.active_index = 2
```

but when I try to apply the active pose:

```
bpy.ops.poselib.apply_pose(pose_index=2)
```

I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.poselib.apply_pose.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

**My question:** Is there an other way to apply the pose? or how can I switch to the correct context?